# MonoGame SpriteFont not working on iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, monogame

We are having trouble loading a plain Arial spritefont as an XNB in MonoGame on iOS. I tried this using the latest develop branch. These were made on Windows, then followed up in Xamarin studio for the iOS part:

- We have a stub XNA project with a content project with `<MonoGamePlatform>iOS</MonoGamePlatform>` defined
- We also have an `<Import>` statement pointing to `MonoGame.ContentPipeline.targets`
- We referenced `MonoGameContentProcessors.dll` in the content project
- Added *.spritefont files with `Content Processor` set to `MonoGame SpriteFont`
- Compiled the project, and copied the resulting XNB into an iOS project with build action set to `Content`.

I tried this in an empty MonoGame project with Arial 9pt, and I get an exception in Texture2D.cs line 228 where it is checking for OpenGL errors.

We have other fonts in our game that are built as a `MonoGame Spritefont from Texture` that work fine. But we can't use this method for some languages (Chinese, especially).

I found some other people have this problem: https://monogame.codeplex.com/workitem/7452

Any ideas? Are fonts working on iOS currently?

Here are my compiled XNBs: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3702398/Fonts.zip

UPDATE: tried Arial 9, 12, 14, 16, as I heard certain sizes were causing issues. None of them worked.

Opened issue here: https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/issues/2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution from discussion [here](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/issues/2005).

- Put the  statement in the XNA main project (not content
  project)
- Put  in the XNA main project
- Put  in the XNA content project

I was setting things only in the content project, which is the wrong place. Tom Spilman mentioned you don't need anything in the content project at all, but I just left it because it works.